# Snapsot to Listview on Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

In my firestore database I have 1000 documents. after user retrieve 1 document I would like to show it in another page as a card in a list page.

The user should see previous retrieved documents in the list when logged in to app again.

Also I do not want to show the same document from the firestore if the user has already retrieved the data from database.

I would like to retrieve document one by one with button press from firestore database and show it in listTile.

With each button press app will add the new snapshot into the list. How could I manage it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) as a local NoSQL database to store all documents that the user retrieves.

Another approach that you can use is to use Hive to store the ids of your documents and when the user logs into your application, then you can get the documents from cache:

```dart
Firestore.instance.collection('collection').document(id).get(source: Source.cache);
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it free to use Hive?

Comment: Yes, Hive is an open-source dart package

Comment: Ok I will try and give you feedback

Comment: I do not want to user retrieve same data from firebase. I mean if I have 10 documents in the database and if user retrieved 1 document app will retrieve document randomly from remaining 9 documents. In a short app will not receive the same document for same user again. How can I do it?

Comment: From what you say I understand that you want an order in the document queries. You can use the `order()` query to sort the documents by created date, for example, and you can use the `limit()` query to get one document. You can store this document and in the next query, you can add the `startAfterDocument()` query to get the next document from the previous one. You can see the firestore query documentation for more information https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: Thank you ! I will check it!

Comment: I would like to retriev document one by one with button press from firestore database and show it in listile.With each button press app will add the new snapshot in to the list. How could I manage it?